# ASP.Net MVC 5 Cookie loses expiration upon return from the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

This simple code has left me perplexed.

From this controller action method, I create a cookie , give it an expiration and set it to be HttpOnly. The cookie gets created correctly, added to the Response, looks correct on the browser debugger , however when returned back into the same code after refresh , loses expiration and HttpOnly flag. The cookie itself is still there , but the values are lost. If I watch Request.Cookies["mycookie"] back into the same controller/action method after a trip to the browser, the values are gone - the cookie itself is not deleted though.

If somebody understands this behaviour please explain, what might be happening here-

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

           if (this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["mycookie"] == null)
            {
                HttpCookie cookie = Response.Cookies["mycookie"];
                cookie["mycookie"] = "test";
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90);
                cookie.HttpOnly = true;   
               this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line: `return View();`

The cookie cannot be set and then read again (server-side) in the same round trip to the server. So, you need to create a second request for the cookie to be available. The simplest way is to force a second request by calling `RedirectToAction`, although you could use some clever AJAXy way of doing it so it appears to be the same request.

See [this post](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2010/10/19/howto-create-and-remove-cookies-with-asp-net-mvc/) for a working example - here is the part where the cookie is written and deleted.

```
public class CookieController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Cookie");
        cookie.Value = "Hello Cookie! CreatedOn: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

        this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    public ActionResult Remove()
    {
        if (this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("Cookie"))
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Cookie"];
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

}
```

Ashiquizzaman is also correct in that you are not setting the value of the cookie, but that is only half of the problem.